# PyQt messagebox yes or no with an if

Tags: python, pyqt4

So guys.What I want to do is, ask if user wanted to reset the form values.
If yes, reset, if no, popup a messagebox.information to confirm nothing happened.

```
def reset(self):
qm = QtGui.QMessageBox
qm.question(self,'', "Are you sure to reset all the values?", qm.Yes | qm.No)

if qm.Yes:
  self.price_box.setText("0")
  self.results_tax.setText("")
  self.results_window.setText("")
  self.tax_rate.setValue(21)
else:
  qm.information(self,'',"Nothing Changed")
```

But for now, No matter what I choose, the form always got reseted.
Anything wrong with my if statement?
Thanx

Answer (score 31):

It should be:

```
ret = qm.question(self,'', "Are you sure to reset all the values?", qm.Yes | qm.No)

if ret == qm.Yes:
```

Hope it helps!